# How to mock Angular BehaviourSubject when Unit Testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocking

I would like to test my AppComponent when receives a `BehaviourSubject` update or change of state, so my goal is to mock the `authService.authEvent` in my `AppComponent`:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  
  user: any
  loggedIn = false
  
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authService.authEvent.subscribe((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.setLoggedIn(user)
      } else {
        this.setLoggedOut()
      }
    });
  }

  setLoggedIn(user: any) {
    this.user = user
    this.loggedIn = true

  }
```

My AuthService is the following (the authEvent `BehaviourSubject` is the one I would like to mock):

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  authEvent = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  user: any = {}
  
  constructor(

  ) {}


  setUser(user: any) {
    console.log('setUser');
    this.user = { ...user }
    sessionStorage.setItem('app-user', JSON.stringify(this.user))
    this.authEvent.next(this.user)
  }
```

And my Unit test, I know this is not the right way to mock the `BehaviourSubject` but I haven't found any good example how to do it:

```
import { BehaviourSubject } from 'rxjs';

export class MockAuthService {

    authEvent = new BehaviourSubject<any>();

    setUser() {
    //mock implementation
    }
}


describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let mockAuthService;
  
  beforeEach(async(() => {

    mockAuthService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['setUser']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: AuthService, useClass: MockAuthService }
      ],
      schemas: [
        CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

    
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  })

  it('should create the app', () => {
   
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });

 
  describe('ngOnInit', () => {
    it('should call setLoggedIn user if user received from authEvent', () => {
      const mockAuthService = TestBed.get(AuthService);
      const userValue = {userName: 'myUser'};
      const spy = spyOn(mockAuthService, 'authEvent').and.returnValue(of(userValue));
      const spyLoggedOut = spyOn(component, 'setLoggedIn').and.callThrough();

      fixture.detectChanges();

      expect(setLoggedIn).toHaveBeenCalled();
      
    });

  });
  
});
```

I would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three ways to mock the Services:

1. Providing a Mock entity as you did
2. Mocking the instance of the Service in the component.
3. Get the Service instance with TestBed.get() and mock that instance of the Service

Independently, on which way you choose to mock the service, you need to execute the unit test as [fakeAsync](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#async-test-with-fakeasync) because you are working with Observable which responses are not instantaneous.

**1) Providing a Mock entity as you did**

```
import { Subject} from 'rxjs';


describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  const mySubject = new Subject();
  
  beforeEach(async(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: AuthService, useValue: { authEven: mySubject.asObservable()} }
      ],
      schemas: [
        CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

    
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  })

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });

 
  describe('ngOnInit', () => {
    it('should call setLoggedIn user if user received from authEvent', fakeAsync(() => {
      const spyLoggedOut = spyOn(component, 'setLoggedIn');;
      const userValue = {userName: 'myUser'};
      component.ngOnInit();
      mySubject.next(userValue);
      tick();
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(setLoggedIn).toHaveBeenCalled();
      flush();
      
    }));

  });
  
});
```

**2) Mocking the instance of the Service in the component.**

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  
  beforeEach(async(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: AuthService }
      ],
      schemas: [
        CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

    
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  })

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });

 
  describe('ngOnInit', () => {
    it('should call setLoggedIn user if user received from authEvent', fakeAsync(() => {
      const spyLoggedOut = spyOn(component, 'setLoggedIn');
      const userValue = {userName: 'myUser'};
      spyOn(component['authService'], 'authEvent').and.returnValue(of(userValue)); //
      component.ngOnInit();
      tick();
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(setLoggedIn).toHaveBeenCalled();
      flush();
      
    }));

  });
  
});
```

**3) Get the Service instance with TestBed.get() and mock that instance of the Service**

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let authService: AuthService ;
  beforeEach(async(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: AuthService }
      ],
      schemas: [
        CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

    
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    authService = TestBed.get(AuthService);
  })

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });

 
  describe('ngOnInit', () => {
    it('should call setLoggedIn user if user received from authEvent', fakeAsync(() => {
      const spyLoggedOut = spyOn(component, 'setLoggedIn');
      const userValue = {userName: 'myUser'};
      spyOn(authService, 'authEvent').and.returnValue(of(userValue)); //
      component.ngOnInit();
      tick();
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(setLoggedIn).toHaveBeenCalled();
      flush();
      
    }));

  });
  
});
```

I prefer **2) Mocking the instance of the Service in the component.** because it's less code and it is simpler